# How do I temporarily multiply a vector in p5.js?

Tags: javascript, vector, p5.js

I have an object called Boid which has a position and a velocity vector (the direction of movement). When updating the position, I want to apply a factor which the user can control. The following script does not work, however:

```
let speedFactor = 0.1; //ranges from 0 to 2

class Boid {
    constructor(x, y) {
        this.position = createVector(x, y);
        this.velocity = p5.Vector.random2D();
    }

    update() {
        this.position.add(this.velocity * speedFactor); // doesn't work
    }
}
```

I also tried to use things like `speedFactor = createVector(0.1, 0.1)`  or `= [0.1, 0.1]`, but it doesn't work.

If I use `this.velocity.mult(speedFactor)`, this will affect the velocity vector, which I don't want (e.g. because if `speedFactor == 0`, `this.velocity` will get messed up). I have tried to create a copy of the velocity vector to overcome this by using `Object.assign({}, this.velocity)` or `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.velocity))`, but somehow that doesn't work neither.

Most of the time I get the error `p5.Vector.prototype.mult: x, y, or z arguments are either undefined or not a finite number`.

What would be the best to do here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copy the vector, then multiply it with the normal `mult` method

```js
let speedFactor = 0.1; //ranges from 0 to 2

class Boid {
    constructor(x, y) {
        this.position = createVector(x, y);
        this.velocity = p5.Vector.random2D();
    }

    update() {
        this.position.add(this.velocity.copy().mult(speedFactor));
    }
}
```